How can I keep metal cans from rusting in my supply cabinet?
I've been keeping a bunch of different supplies up in a cabinet, various oils and glues and chemical bottles and such. The trouble is, all the metal cans in the one side have been rusting! We live in a dry climate and the cabinet is dry in the garage. A can of bug spray or WD-40 in the "chemical" half of the cabinet gets super rusty in half a year, whereas a fifteen year old can of spray paint in the other half still looks brand new!
This is very similar to the situation at Rapid and extreme oxidation of steel in chemical cabinet and my cans/rust look almost identical. And the culprit could be identical but my question is broader: is there anything else here that could be the culprit, and more importantly is there a way I can store these without causing this trouble?
Here's my own best guesses as to what it might be:

The muriatic acid was blamed in the other answer; is it the prime culprit? Chlorine bleach also seems like nasty stuff, would it cause rust? Hydrogen peroxide breaks down to water and extra oxygen right? Would PCB etchant mess stuff up outside the bottle? What about the acetone, which seems to have disappeared out of the bottle much more rapidly than I remember using it?
And with any/all of these things, is there a better (but still space/budget friendly…) way to store them than the manufacturer's own container? How "contagious" are they — if I leave them out of the cabinet will it/they just destroy the entire garage instead?

wipe exposed metal surfaces with wd40 while still shiny to prevent rust.

Ferric chloride in a Radio Shack bottle. That's some vintage stuff! :-) The acetone isn't your problem - that stuff ships in metal gallon jugs.

The acid you have is in a plastic container same as the linked answer, so is probably the suspect.  Maybe a second cabinet, one for plastic containers and one for metal containers.  Would like to know if the 15 year old paint is still good?

@crip659 Thanks, and yeah some of the old spray paint still works! The paint in cans so-so, haven't tried most of it and wouldn't be surprised if some of it needs tossing.

It's the muriatic acid, full stop. None of the other materials will cause localized rusting like that, where exposed steel within a short distance gets rusty, but a little further away, exposed steel is fine. I've even seen it happen to plain steel finished in baked enamel paint.
Muriatic acid is hydrogen chloride gas dissolved in water; i.e., hydrochloric acid. The plastic jug retains the water no problem, but the hydrogen chloride gas diffuses right through the plastic, slowly but steadily, and causes nearby steel to rust. I know that muriatic acid in water removes rust. What can I say, it is what it is!
I'll tell you the final long-term solution that I found, which has been working effectively for over 10 years.

I poured the muriatic acid into a glass 1-gallon (4 liter) jug. The
cap is Bakelite and the cap liner is a lacquered fiber disc. I
labeled the bottle with its contents and a skull and crossbones.
I keep the glass jug inside a covered plastic tub with a capacity of
about 2-3 gallons (8-12 liters). The cover is not air-tight.
I poured pelletized lawn lime (primarily calcium carbonate) into the
plastic tub to surround the glass jug about half-way up. Any form of
calcium carbonate would be fine, such as marble chips, but I had lawn
lime on hand and it's inexpensive.

The foremost reason for surrounding the glass jug with calcium carbonate is to neutralize the acid if the glass jug should break in some freak accident. However, it also serves to react with and neutralize any stray molecules of airborne hydrogen chloride in the tub.
This has been 100% effective in preventing rust on nearby cans, metal shelves, etc.
